# Pass information from an input to another component in another file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, react-props

I'm having a problem, it's been a few days, I'm studying about React and Typescript and I'm developing a temperature application, I'm stopped in a part, where I want the user to click on the submit form, the information that was typed in the input is passed to another component.

Follow my two codes below

CityWeatherSearch.tsx

```
import { MagnifyingGlass } from 'phosphor-react'
import { FormEvent, useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import * as Styled from './style'   


export function  CityWeatherSearch(){   

    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const [city,setCity] = useState('');

    function handleClick(event:FormEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const inputCity = inputRef?.current?.value;
        console.log({
            inputCity, city
        });
    }
    
    return(
        <>
            <Styled.BoxSearchCity>
                <div className="headerSearch">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" placeholder='Procurar Cidade...' ref={inputRef} onChange={
                            event => setCity(event.target.value)} />
                        <button type="submit" onClick={handleClick}>
                            <MagnifyingGlass/>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="bodySearch">
                    {city}
                </div>
            </Styled.BoxSearchCity>
        </>
    )
}
```

MainWeatherLive.tsx

```
import {Clock} from 'phosphor-react'
import { useFetch } from '../../GetData/useFetch'
import * as Styled from './style'



type DataWeather = {               
    name: string,    
    condition:{
        text:string,
        icon:string
    },
    temp_c:number,
    hour:[{
        temp_c:number,
        time:string,
        condition:{
            text:string,
            icon:string
        }
    }]

}


export function MainWeatherLive(){
    const {dataLocation: dataWeatherApi, isFetching, dataCurrent:dataCurrentApi, dataForecast:forecastApi}
     = useFetch<DataWeather>('/v1/forecast.json?key=aff6fe0e7f5d4f3fa0611008221406&q=Guarulhos?days=1&aqi=no&alerts=no');      
    return(
        <>
            <Styled.HeaderBox>
                <h6>Weather Now</h6>                
            </Styled.HeaderBox>
            <Styled.Container>    
                {isFetching && 
                    <p>Carregando...</p>
                }            
                <div className="mainInformation">
                    <div className="temperatura">
                        <span>{dataCurrentApi?.temp_c}º</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        A cidade é {cityName}
                    </div>
                    <div className="boxCidade">
                        <div className="cidade">
                            <span>{dataWeatherApi?.name}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="tempoHoras">
                            <span>
                            {new Date().toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR',{hour12:false, hour:'numeric',minute:'numeric'})} - {new Date().toLocaleDateString()}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                    <div className="iconeTem">
                        <img src={dataCurrentApi?.condition.icon} alt={dataCurrentApi?.condition.text} />                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="footerBox">
                    <div className="headerFooter">
                        <Clock/> 
                        <span>Horários</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="listaHorarios">
                        <ul className="boxTT">
                            {
                                forecastApi?.hour?.map(weatherA =>{
                                    const hourTemp = weatherA.time.split(" ")[1].replace(":00","");
                                    const hourTempNumber:number = +hourTemp;                                    
                                    const hourNow = new Date().getHours();
                                    return(   
                                        <>
                                        {
                                            hourTempNumber == hourNow &&
                                            <li>
                                                <div className="titulo" key={weatherA.temp_c}>
                                                    <span>{hourTempNumber}</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="temperatura">
                                                    <img src={weatherA.condition.icon} alt={weatherA.condition.text} />
                                                    <span>{dataCurrentApi?.temp_c}º</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        } 
                                        
                                        {
                                            hourTempNumber > hourNow &&
                                            <li>
                                                <div className="titulo" key={weatherA.temp_c}>
                                                    <span>{hourTempNumber}</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="temperatura">
                                                    <img src={weatherA.condition.icon} alt={weatherA.condition.text} />
                                                    <span>{weatherA.temp_c}º</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        }  
                                        </>                                        
                                        )
                                })
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Styled.Container>
        </>
    )
}
```

Weather.tsx

```
import { CityWeatherSearch } from "./WeatherC/CityWeatherSearch";
import { MainWeatherLive } from "./WeatherC/MainWeatherLive";
import { WeatherDetails } from "./WeatherC/WeatherDetails";
import coldImage from '../assets/cold.jpg'
import sunImage from '../assets/sun.jpg'
import rainImage from '../assets/rain.jpg'
import nightVideo from '../assets/night.mp4'
import night from '../assets/night.jpg'


export const TypesWeather = {
    NIGHT:{
        video:{
            source: nightVideo
        },
        image:{
            source: night
        }
    },
    OVERCAST:{
        video:{
            source: nightVideo
        },
        image:{
            source: night
        }
    },
    COLD:{
        image:{
            source: coldImage,
            title: 'Frio'
        }
    },
    SUN:{
        image:{
            source: sunImage,
            title: 'Verão'
        }
    },
    RAIN:{
        image:{
            source: rainImage,
            title: 'Chuva'
        }
    },
};

export type TypesWeatherV2 = keyof typeof TypesWeather;



export function Weather(){
    return (
           <>
            <div className="globalSite" style={{background:`linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.85) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.85) 100%),url(${TypesWeather.RAIN.image.source})`}}>
            </div>
            <div className="boxAllWeather">
                <div className="backgroundWeather" style={{backgroundImage:`url(${TypesWeather.RAIN.image.source})`}}></div>
                <div className="boxAllInff">                    
                    <div className="mainWeather">                
                        <MainWeatherLive />
                    </div>
                    <div className="otherInfoWeather">
                        <CityWeatherSearch />
                        <WeatherDetails />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
           </>    

    )
}
```

I want to pass the city typed in CityWeatherSearch.tsx to MainWeatherLive.tsx. Where is the space 'A cidade é {cityName}' reserved, I've tried everything, but I haven't been able to, could you help me?

Comment: Where is your CityWeatherSearch in MainWeatherLive? How are they communicating?

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal code example (maybe a code sandbox) so we can see the full picture of how these two components are working together? Without that it will be almost impossible  to help. It would also be helpful to know what you have tried.

Comment: Both Mainweatherlive and cityweathersearch are in the weather.tsx file, I edited my question and added this file

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways:

1. parent -> child : use props
2. child -> parent : use callback/event emitter
3. no direct relationship : consider using state management tool like
   redux

Answer (score 0):

Just lift your state uo to the parent component and pass if to the cild components as props:

```js
function WeatherPage() {
  const [city,setCity] = useState('');
  return (
    <>
      <CityWeatherSearch city={city} setCity={setCity}/>
      //...
      <MainWeatherLive city={city}/>
      //...
    </>
  )
}

function CityWeatherSearch({city, setCity}) {
   // your code here, only without const [city, setCity] useState()
}

function MainWeatherLive({city}) {
   // your code here, now you can access city
}
```

If your two components don't have a direct common parent and you don't want to pass down `city` and `setCity` through a deep component hierarchy, think about using `useContext` to share state within your application.